# how to make pop up on left side of each icon in list view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am making a demo of list view. Rows are is generated dynamically (when user press add button).I want to show a pop up screen on left side of icon.But In my demo it  is opening on center on every row.Can it is possible it only open on left side of icon or each row  (as show in image)

http://jsfiddle.net/FZQ8D/34/

```
$(document).on("click", "i.test_h", function(e){
    alert("pop up open");
    $("#Mainnavpanel").popup("open");
});
```

![enter image description here][2]

I am getting this output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override `x` and `y` position of *popup*.

```
$("#Mainnavpanel").popup("open", {
  y: $(this).offset().top + ($(this).height() / 2),
  x: $(this).offset().left
});
```

Or `positionTo`.

```
$("#Mainnavpanel").popup("open", {
   positionTo: $(this)
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/4ajeB/)**

Comment: @user2535959 sure, this is another irrelevant question to your OP :)

Comment: @user2535959 simply, add listeners the same way you added to listview buttons.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4ajeB/2/ I am able to get event of edit but how to know on which element it click ..I want to show alert of id.Example when i click "tc_2" icon .it show pop up .on click "edit" it show id of "tc_2"

Comment: @mar it is possible to get ID

Comment: @user2535959 pls post another question.